# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'impl'

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

After running my program, I am getting a Output, but I also get this error message.

```
Exception ignored in: <function Model.__del__ at 0x7f02ba33b430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deepspeech/__init__.py", line 43, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'impl'
```

Here is the code - Here I am trying to convert an wv audio file into text using deepspeech library.

```
from deepspeech import Model
import numpy as np
import os
import wave
import json

from IPython.display import Audio
from IPython.display import clear_output

model_file_path = 'deepspeech-0.8.2-models.pbmm'
lm_file_path = 'deepspeech-0.8.2-models.scorer'
beam_width = 100
lm_alpha = 0.93
lm_beta = 1.18

model = Model(model_file_path)
model.enableExternalScorer(lm_file_path)

model.setScorerAlphaBeta(lm_alpha, lm_beta)
model.setBeamWidth(beam_width)


def read_wav_file(filename):
    with wave.open(filename, 'rb') as w:
        rate = w.getframerate()
        frames = w.getnframes()
        buffer = w.readframes(frames)

    return buffer, rate



def transcribe(audio_file):
    buffer, rate = read_wav_file(audio_file)
    data16 = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.int16)

    
    return model.stt(data16)


print(transcribe('speech.wav'))
```

Comment: DeepSpeech is in an early development phase. You didn't give any indication what version you are using (also 0.8?). Please head over to their Discourse and report some more information: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/what-and-how-to-report-if-you-need-support/62071

Comment: Hello, I am using version 0.8.2

Comment: Sorry, this was just an example. You obviously didn't read the link. Just check the code in the repo to know more about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Importing IPython is causing the issue, try running your code without it and it should work.

```
from deepspeech import Model
import numpy as np
import os
import wave
import json

model_file_path = 'deepspeech-0.8.2-models.pbmm'
lm_file_path = 'deepspeech-0.8.2-models.scorer'
beam_width = 100
lm_alpha = 0.93
lm_beta = 1.18

model = Model(model_file_path)
model.enableExternalScorer(lm_file_path)

model.setScorerAlphaBeta(lm_alpha, lm_beta)
model.setBeamWidth(beam_width)


def read_wav_file(filename):
    with wave.open(filename, 'rb') as w:
        rate = w.getframerate()
        frames = w.getnframes()
        buffer = w.readframes(frames)

    return buffer, rate



def transcribe(audio_file):
    buffer, rate = read_wav_file(audio_file)
    data16 = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.int16)

    
    return model.stt(data16)


print(transcribe('speech.wav'))
```